# Unable to delete parse object from android app

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

So I am currently saving a username in my parse installation in android like this:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                    installation.put("user", username);
                    installation.saveInBackground();
```

I then make a query by username to send pushes to a specific device. If I want to now 'unlink' that device from receiving pushes, I have to delete the row from my parse installation table where the username is the username stored in the app.

I have tried pretty much everything, and am now down to this:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                ParseObject object = installation.getParseObject("user");
                object.deleteInBackground();
```

but alas, this also doesn't work. I have also tried `installation.deleteInBackground()` but this too failed. How can I remove this parseobject or installation from the device so that it can no longer receive pushes?

Comment: double check the api on what Installation.put(key, val) actually does. Make sure you retrieve exactly the object you need before the 'delete' ... https://parse.com/docs/android/api/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot delete installation object from client - you can only do it from Parse Cloud Code with master key.

You can simply do the following:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                        installation.remove("user");
                        installation.saveInBackground();
```

OR if that doesn't work then try:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                    installation.put("user", "" OR null);
                    installation.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried this, but hey, this works. The only issue is that app's "installation" is still sitting in my installation table on the parse control panel, but there are no more pushes to that user.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is:

```
ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
installation.deleteInBackground();
```

If that doesn't work, then it's true that you can delete Installation objects from parse only via CloudCode (with master key).

I don't really see a why would parse allow doing that because you're actually running the application so would you want to delete its installation object - don't know what would be the behaviour.